# Undefined reference when calling a class member function from another static function

Tags: c++, qt, static-methods

So I had a static function in C++ and needed to call a member function of a class. Obviously one cannot call a member function from a static method without specifying the instance of the class that the member function belongs to. In my case the class required to instantiated only once so I came up with the following code:

```
#include <QAndroidJniObject>
#include <QDebug>

class JavaListener : public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    JavaListener() = default;

    static JavaListener* getInstance(){
        if (mThis == nullptr) // avoid creation of new instances
            mThis = new JavaListener;
        return mThis;
    }

    static JavaListener* mThis;

signals:
    // signals can be seen as just "functions" in Qt
    void messageReceived(QString const &message);
};

JavaListener* JavaListener::mThis = nullptr;


static void receiveFromJava(JNIEnv */*env*/, jobject /*obj*/, jstring message)
{
    JavaListener* j = JavaListener::getInstance();
    QAndroidJniObject messageObject(message);
    // emit is not really necessary
    emit j->messageReceived(messageObject.toString());

    qDebug() << "MESSAGE FROM JAVA" << message;
}
```

However I get the following error:

> error: error: undefined reference to 'JavaListener::messageReceived(QString const&)'

on the following line:
`emit j->messageReceived(messageObject.toString());`

Comment: Where do you defined `messageReceived`?

Comment: It is defined as a signal in my Qt class:
`signals: void messageReceived(QString const &message);`

Comment: That's not a definition, that's a declaration.  You need to define the function somewhere.  A function definition would look like `void JavaListener::messageReceived(QString const &message) { code }`

Comment: @NathanOliver ok so I cannot directly emit my signal from my static function?

Comment: I'm not sure how Qt's signals and slots works but `messageReceived` should need to be defined somewhere.

Comment: &NathanOliver: In Qt, the definition of all "signals" is created automatically by the meta object compiler (MOC). It should not be in the code written by the developer.

Comment: Its `Q_OBJECT` macro was missing in your class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @NathanOliver 's suggestion, I created a function inside my `JavaListener` class:

```
    void onMessageReceived(QString const &message){
        emit messageReceived(message);
    }
```

and then called this in my static method. (I am not sure why a Qt signal cannot be emitted directly).

Answer (score 0):

Follow the singleton code template and don't make the object keeper member public, it must be **private** So, do something like this:

```
private: 
static JavaListener* mThis = nullptr;
```

then you can do something like this:

```
JavaListener::getInstance()->messageReceived(messageObject.toString());
```

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. Once you reach 50 reputation here, you will be able to post comments.

Comment: `JavaListener.h:18:26: error: non-const static data member must be initialized out of line`

Answer (score 0):

You need to run qmake first. The signal meta code will be generated by this and then the signal-code shall be there. An then the undefined symbol-issue should be solved as well.

In Qt-Creator just try "**Run QMake**".